# How to access a local http server on windows by its hostname

Tags: networking, windows, hostname

I need to access a local windows HTTP server by `hostname` because its `ip` isn't static. I already tried `winbind`, but it doesn't work as expect. I can ping the server by `ping <hostname>` but not by `ping http://<hostname>`. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual page of ping](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping):

> ping [ -LRUbdfnqrvVaAB] [ -c count] [ -i interval] [ -l preload] [ -p pattern] [ -s packetsize] [ -t ttl] [ -w deadline] [ -F flowlabel] [ -I interface] [ -M hint] [ -Q tos] [ -S sndbuf] [ -T timestamp option] [ -W timeout] [ hop ...] destination

Hrmpf...  I was going to tell you that the manual shows that `destination` should be an IP address or a hostname and not a Fully Qualified Domain Name With Protocol (FQDNWP), but it doesn't...

Therefore: Nope, you can't do that, but you *could*:

```
telnet hostname.domain.com 80
```

which would connect you to port 80 (http) of the FQDN